# React Drag n Drop PUT request after props

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am building an application that requires a table of items to be sorted and change the orderNumber of them depending on their sorting. I installed and utilized a library called react-dnd to handle the functionality of sorting/ordering, and its working great so far. The issue im having is the update. When a user moves one of the items, I need to send a PUT request to the api and update its orderNumber. It was working last night great, here is my code.

The ListItem (Item that is being sorted and updated):

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {DragSource, DropTarget} from 'react-dnd';
import sdk from '../../js/sdk';
import ItemTypes from './ItemTypes';

const itemSource = {
    beginDrag(props) {
        return {id: props.id};
    }
};

const itemTarget = {
    hover(props, monitor) {
        const draggedId = monitor.getItem().id;
        if (draggedId !== props.id) {
            props.swapItems(draggedId, props.id);
        }
    }
};


const DragSourceDecorator = DragSource(ItemTypes.ITEM, itemSource, (connect, monitor) => {
    return {
        connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    };
});

const DropTargetDecorator = DropTarget(ItemTypes.ITEM, itemTarget, (connect) => {
    return {connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()};
});

class SwagBagItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this._handleDelete = this._handleDelete.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const swagbagItemCpy = Object.assign({}, nextProps.swagbagItem);
        delete swagbagItemCpy.id;

        if (nextProps) {
            sdk.put(`swagbags/${nextProps.swagbag.id}/items/${nextProps.swagbagItem.id}`, swagbagItemCpy)
                .done((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                }).fail((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
            ;
        }
    }

    _handleDelete(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this Swagbag Item?')) {
            sdk.delete(`swagbags/${this.props.swagbag.id}/items/${this.props.swagbagItem.id}`)
                .done(() => {
                    console.log('Swagbag Item remove!');
                }).then(() => {
                    this.props.loadSwagBags();
                });
            }
        }

    render() {
        const {swagbagItem} = this.props;
        return this.props.connectDragSource(this.props.connectDropTarget(
            <tr className="swagbag-item">
                <td>{swagbagItem.id}</td>
                <td><Link to={`${this.props.swagbag.id}/items/${swagbagItem.id}`}>{swagbagItem.name}</Link></td>
                <td>{swagbagItem.uri}</td>
                <td>
                    <div className="btn-group btn-group-xs pull-right" role="group">
                        <Link to={`${this.props.swagbag.id}/items/${swagbagItem.id}/edit`} className="btn btn-info">Edit</Link>
                        <Link to={`${this.props.swagbag.id}/items/${swagbagItem.id}`} className="btn btn-info">View</Link>
                        <button className="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onClick={this._handleDelete}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ));
    }
}


SwagBagItem.propTypes = {
    loadSwagBags: PropTypes.func,
    params: PropTypes.object,
    swagbag: PropTypes.object,
    swagbagItem: PropTypes.object,
};

export default DropTargetDecorator(DragSourceDecorator(SwagBagItem));
```

The container or list that holds these items:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {DragDropContext} from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import sdk from '../../js/sdk';

import Nav from '../Nav';

import SwagBagItem from '../SwagBagItem';

class SwagBagItemsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            swagbag: null,
            swagbagItems: [],
        };

        this._loadSwagBags = this._loadSwagBags.bind(this);
        this._compareItems = this._compareItems.bind(this);
        this._swapItems = this._swapItems.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this._loadSwagBags();
    }

    _compareItems(item1, item2) {
        return item1.orderNumber - item2.orderNumber;
    }

    _swapItems(itemNo1, itemNo2) {
        const items = this.state.swagbagItems;
        let item1 = items.filter(item => item.id === itemNo1)[0];
        let item2 = items.filter(item => item.id === itemNo2)[0];
        let item1Order = item1.orderNumber;
        item1.orderNumber = item2.orderNumber;
        item2.orderNumber = item1Order;

        items.sort(this._compareItems);
        this.setState({swagbagItems: items});
    }

    _loadSwagBags() {
        sdk.getJSON(`swagbags/${this.props.params.id}`)
            .done((result) => {
                this.setState({swagbag: result});
            })
            .then(() => {
                sdk.getJSON(`swagbags/${this.props.params.id}/items?fields=id,name,summary,uri,itemImageFile,orderNumber`).done((results) => {
                    this.setState({swagbagItems: results});
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        let swagbagItems = null;
        if (this.state.swagbagItems) {
            swagbagItems = this.state.swagbagItems.map((item) => {
                return <SwagBagItem
                            loadSwagBags={this._loadSwagBags}
                            swagbag={this.state.swagbag}
                            swagbagItem={item}
                            key={item.id}
                            id={item.id}
                            swapItems={this._swapItems}
                        />;
            });
        }
        if (!this.state.swagbag) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Swagbag Items</h1>
                <Nav swagbag={this.state.swagbag} />
                <table className="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>id</th>
                            <th>name</th>
                            <th>uri</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {swagbagItems}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <Link to={`swagbags/createItem/swagbagid/${this.state.swagbag.id}`} className="btn btn-success">Add Item</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

SwagBagItemsList.propTypes = {
    params: PropTypes.object,
};

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(SwagBagItemsList);
```

It is making the PUT request, but its making hundreds of them in a row from just moving one object. I cant for the life of me figure out why. This puts a severe lag on the application and makes it unresponsive. Am I going about this the right way, and if so, what is the solution to this?

EDIT #1: Woke up today and the application is working fine. Unfortunately this is going in production, so before that I have to recreate the bug of 800+ PUT requests and figure it out. Might put a bounty on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it so that it sends the update once it's finished dragging, there's an endDrag function you can add to your DragSource (http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source.html) that will only be fired once and will only be fired upon finishing the drag. So if you remove your api call from componentWillReceiveProps and move it to the source like this:

```
const itemSource = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    return {
      id: props.id,
      swagbagId: props.swagbag.id,
      swagbagItem: props.swagbagItem,
    };
  },
  endDrag(props, monitor) {
    const item = monitor.getItem();
    sdk.put(`swagbags/${item.swagbagId}/items/${item.swagbagItem.id}`, item.swagbagItem)
       .done((result) => {
           console.log(result);
       }).fail((error) => {
           console.log(error);
       })
    ;
  },
};
```

It should only make the call one time (I can't perfectly predict that without knowing what's in swagbag and swagbagItem but I think it should). Note that I'm using the getItem() function from the DragSource monitor (http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source-monitor.html) to retrieve what was passed in upon beginDrag.